# Как подключить препроцессор CSS к HTML?

Tags: html, css, препроцессор

[image: как это реализовать ?]

Как реализовать вот такое подлючение препроцессоров ?

Comment: Это map-файлы - по ним браузер строит соответствие.

Comment: как мне подробней про это узнать?

Comment: Начать с поиска по теме Javascript Source Map, вот например https://habr.com/post/148098/ и вот https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Javascript+Source+Map&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8